# Spring, AOP - how to define the aspect after Hibernate DAO transaction closes

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions, aspectj, dao

My project is Web app with Spring and Hibernate. I need to perform some routine operation on the data returned by my DAO layer and transaction is committed and session is closed. I try to use aspects with annotations like this:

```
@AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(* com.dao..*.*(..))", returning = "result")
public void afterReturning(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object result){
    processResult(result);
}
```

or using

```
@Around("execution(* com.dao..*.*(..))")
```

but in either event I got Hibernate exceptions like this:

**org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance -    save the transient instance before flushing**

Off course everything works if I just apply that same operation in my service:

```
public void serviceMethod(Object param) {
    Object result = dao.getObject(param);
    processResult(result);
}
```

'Cause I need to use processResult against every DAO method's result I am reluctant to use the latter approach and would be grateful for some advice on how to use either aspects or some other alternative way on doing so....

Comment: Put an order annotation on your aspect and make it execute inside the transaction, which you should also give an order (which is an attribute on `<tx:annotation-driven />`.